# PCL filters not foud

Tags: qt, point-cloud-library

I'm working with Qt and my current project includes OpenCV and OpenNI

I've installed PCL with apt-get and changed my CmakeLists.txt but Cmake only finds pcl/commons and pcl/io

I want to use the others such as filters or registration. What should I do?

Comment: Have you compiled PCL or do you use a binary package ?
For the former, check that the cmake option BUILD_module are set to ON for the modules you need.
As for your CMakeLists, how does it look ? A base would be :
`FIND_PACKAGE(PCL COMPONENTS common io filters registration)`

Comment: Thanks for asking, I use a binary package and the file I have is FIND_PACKAGE(PCL 1.3 REQUIRED COMPONENTS common io filters registration)

Comment: `REQUIRED` and `COMPONENTS` are exclusive options. Anyway complete your questions with code snippets and the results of your cmake / compilation

Comment: I've quitted REQUIRED and now I can find them but in CMake it sais that 'Target "main" request linking to directory "PATH/" Targets may link only to libraries. CMake is dropping the item'